# JavaScript returns all alerts instead of one. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, alert, innerhtml

So, I am trying to beef up my tip calculator app in JS a bit. I decided to add an alert underneath each form if there is no value added and unfortunately it's partially not working.
I've got 3 forms (amount of a bill, choosing what kind of tip the user wants to give in percentage and how many people are sharing bill. Problem is, JS launches all three alerts despite missing only one or two values. Also, I wonder how can I get rid of alerts as those remain even after adding all values to the calculator.
It worked before adding alert1, alert2 and alert3.

```js
const calculateTip =() => {
    const cost = document.querySelector('.amount').value;
    const service = document.querySelector('.service').value;
    const people = document.querySelector('.numOfPeo').value;
    const alert1 = document.querySelector('#alert-1').innerHTML = "Please tell me amount of your bill!"
    const alert2 = document.querySelector('#alert-2').innerHTML = "Please tell me how your service was!"
    const alert3 = document.querySelector('#alert-3').innerHTML = "Please tell me how many people are sharing!"

    if (cost === "") {
        alert1
    }

    if (service === 0) {
        return alert2
    }

    if (people === "" || people <= 1) {
        return alert3
    }

    const tip = cost * service / 100;
    const total = tip / people;

    document.getElementById('totalTip').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = total;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', calculateTip);
```

Comment: use `else-if` to branch the flow, Change`if (service === 0) {` to `else if (service === 0) {` and so on

Comment: use if / else and switch case and can you please also add html tag, will batter to understand :-)

Answer (score 1):

you are setting innerHTML for everything. try setting it within the conditional

```
const cost = document.querySelector('.amount').value;
const service = document.querySelector('.service').value;
const people = document.querySelector('.numOfPeo').value;

if (cost === "") {
    document.querySelector('#alert-1').innerHTML = "Please tell me amount of your bill!"
} else if (service === 0) {
    document.querySelector('#alert-2').innerHTML = "Please tell me how your service was!"
} else if (people === "" || people <= 1) {
    document.querySelector('#alert-3').innerHTML = "Please tell me how many people are sharing!"
}

const tip = cost * service / 100;
const total = tip / people;

document.getElementById('totalTip').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = total;
```

When you code `const alert1 = document.querySelector('#alert-1').innerHTML = "Please tell me amount of your bill!"` what you are actually doing is setting `alert1` to `"Please tell me amount of your bill!"` and the `innerHTML` attribute also to `"Please tell me amount of your bill!"`. In other words, your alert constants are unnecessary as your only goal is to set the innerHTML for certain cases. These cases are represented by your `if` logic. So it makes sense to move these `innerHTML` statements to your conditional logic and remove your const variables entirely. Additionally, in order to make sure only one alert fires at a time I added `if else` logic. And since the return value of our event listener function does not matter, there is no reason to `return` anything

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although I am still experiencing difficulties with a code.

When I do not enter any value only first message does fire up.
Message under second form does not fire up at all.
Alerts remain even though I enter value to all forms. Any thoughts how can I get rid of them whilst all values are entered?

Comment: It would help to understand the html you are working with but from what I know, this is what I can say: if you want each alert to be populated no matter what then DO NOT use `else if`. Just use single `if` cases like you did originally. As far as clearing the form you need to set `innerHTML = ""` when the input is correct. This would be along the lines of `cost.addEventListener('input', (e) => { if (e.target.value === '') alert.innerHTML === "" });`

Comment: Overall man, I would not suggest setting innerHTML for form control warnings. You should create the elements in html and set them to `display: none;`. When the form has an error then add a css class to set the display to block/initial or whatever. If you want to setup a code pen or something I can help you refine it

Comment: I have tried to do it, but I am absolutely clueless at this point. If you help with me with refining it I would be grateful.
https://codepen.io/tgruszczynski91/pen/NWGWvaG

Comment: first things first, you have no elements with `id="alert-1"`, `id="alert-2"`, `id="alert-3"`. because of this when you call `document.querySelector("#alert-1")` it returns `null`. you then proceed to access the attribute `innerHTML` on `null` which throws an error and stops your code from executing. you need to create elements with these ids as well as use the code i setup above

Comment: alright here: https://codepen.io/pmurpmur/pen/dyYyZmz . if you are learning make sure to understand what is happening. basically i added your ids to the `small` tags. I then set the innerHTML of the small tags to either the warning string or an empty string if no error exists. this way it will clear if there is no error. currently you do not handle errors the best way possible. check out the if conditional i wrapped around your calculate code. you'll want to handle negative numbers and what not but remember that every input comes to you as a string, so convert them to integers